# Memory leak Java, HEAP size not reducing

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory

So I grow up with C++ and have no problem with memory management whatsoever building C++ programs. But the time has come the market is asking me to understand and learn Java. Okay no problem! After spending a lot of time developing Java applications I keep hitting my head with this memory management in Java.

I took one of my applications and trying to understand how to keep a low heap size. The image bellow is a print-screen from VisualVM 2.0.1. The numbers represent the times I call the `CollectData()` function. As you can see, call number 1 is all okay, but when I call it again it grows with **125MB** and keeps going on. I don't understand why? (So I paste my code bellow, so maybe someone could help me explaining whats going on).

So I tried basically everything with playing with the `null` and `new` operators, without any success. Also I tried playing with the `System.gc()` function.

[image: VisualVM]

```
public void CollectData() {
    /// Variables
    taBB.setText("");
    Connection con;   
    String tb_name_hours = "table_name";
    String tb_name_minutes = "table_name";
    String db_name = "database_name";

    List<TickerIntervalData> data_set_mins = new ArrayList<TickerIntervalData>();
    List<TickerIntervalData> data_set_hours = new ArrayList<TickerIntervalData>();
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000");
    DecimalFormat dec2 = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000000");


    ///
    try {
        /// Connect
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + tfIP.getText() + ":" + tfPort.getText();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(2);     
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, tfUser.getText(), String.valueOf(tfPassword.getPassword()));     


        // Use db_name
        Statement stt = con.createStatement();
        stt.execute("USE " + db_name);        


        // Get rows from hour table
        ResultSet res = stt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tb_name_hours);
        while (res.next()) {
            TickerIntervalData new_record = new TickerIntervalData();
            new_record.setOpen(res.getDouble("open"));
            new_record.setHighest(res.getDouble("highest")); 
            new_record.setLowest(res.getDouble("lowest")); 
            new_record.setClose(res.getDouble("close")); 
            new_record.setVolume(res.getDouble("volume")); 
            new_record.setBv(res.getDouble("bv")); 
            new_record.setTimestamp(res.getString("time")); 
            data_set_hours.add(new_record);
        } 


        // Get rows from minute table
        res = stt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tb_name_minutes);
        while (res.next()) {
            TickerIntervalData new_record = new TickerIntervalData();
            new_record.setOpen(res.getDouble("open"));
            new_record.setHighest(res.getDouble("highest")); 
            new_record.setLowest(res.getDouble("lowest")); 
            new_record.setClose(res.getDouble("close")); 
            new_record.setVolume(res.getDouble("volume")); 
            new_record.setBv(res.getDouble("bv")); 
            new_record.setTimestamp(res.getString("time")); 
            data_set_mins.add(new_record);
        } 


        // Free resources
        res.close();
        stt.close();
        res = null;
        stt = null;


        // 
        data_set_hours.clear();
        data_set_hours = null;
        data_set_mins.clear();
        data_set_mins = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        taBB.setText(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn to use a profiler. VisualVM is a good choice if you don’t use netbeans.

Comment: If you have an exception you don’t close the database connection

Comment: what is your xms and xmx? which gc you use? do you use any frameworks or vanilla java?
Can you try keep calling this function more times than 3 times, do u get OOM?

Comment: Memory management in Java is very different compared to c++. Do you eventually get an out of memory error? If you don't, there's no actual problem here. That said, you're not closing the database connection, and you're leaving the result set and statement open when an exception happens.  There is no RAII in Java, you have to use try-finally or "try with resources" to guarantee things are closed

Comment: From my experience there is very little you can do to to influence the orange curve of allocated memory. All modern JVMs are optimized for server-use which in regards of memory management often means it allocates when it thinks it requires more memory up until it's maximum but only seldom de-allocates actual OS memory. I guess this saves some OS handling overhead. As long as the blue curve of used memory goes back down everything usually is fine. You could pre-size your arraylists to make the whole thing more memory-efficient. Or define a maximum heapsize if it really matters for your use-case

Comment: Also you don't have to set resources (objects) to `null` to free them.  This will be done automatically when the the object goes out of scope.  (I'm pointing this out because what you have right now is poor practice, and for Java you should remove those lines "releasing" the objects.)

Comment: Some other thoughts: calling `exception.toString()` like this hides a lot of useful information, you should either print the full error to the console or log it (the latter is best).  Java code style conventions use camel case, and not underscores.  For "learning Java" please use the correct code style.

Comment: A good way to verify if anything is wrong with your code could be to start your program with param `-Xmx200m` This limits your maximum heap and should encourage the JVM to do a less-lazy job on garbage collection. If you run out of memory information from the first or second run might indeed be non-freeable in some other parts of your code